# .range() and .cell() equal methods?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using an array of data to enter data into various areas on my sheet. I am having trouble with the range that I want to update. I can get the .Range ("T12") to work. but I need to use the .range(.cells (12,19),(.cells (12,19)) because I will be advancing the rows. 
Shouldn't the two methods below be equal?

```
Set pastCommentCell = Sheets(copyScenario).Range(Sheets (copyScenario).Cells(12, 19), Sheets(copyScenario).Cells(12, 19))
pastCommentCell.Value = arrAggCom(arrCount, 2)

Set pastCommentCell = Sheets(copyScenario).Range("T12")
pastCommentCell.Value = arrAggCom(arrCount, 2)
```

The range.cells() method does nothing. No errors, just doesn't do anything). Looks like in the value2 it shows empty when pasteCommentCell is set.
The range("T12") updates to the new value as expected. And when pasteCommentCell is set before updating the value, value2 shows 5555 (as expected).

Comment: The space between `Sheets` and `(copyScenario)` suggests you typed that in manually instead of copying from your actual code, which might mean your actual code is different. If it's not, put a breakpoint on `pastCommentCell.Value = arrAggCom(arrCount, 2)` and examine `pastCommentCell.Address`.

Comment: In your first example, have you tried ` pastCommentCeel(0).value` ? Maybe it takes the range as an array with only 1 entry in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to address cell T12, you should use `.Cells(12, 20)` rather than `.Cells(12, 19)` ...

Comment: Thanks Peter. I knew it was something dumb I was doing.